# Website log in using java app

Tags: java, html, url, servlets

I would like my app to:
1) connect with my bank's website (https://e-bank.credit-agricole.pl/)
2) put login and password in empty forms
3) "hit" submin/proceed/login button
4) print out some data such as available money amount, account number and so on

Any idea how should I start? I know that I have to make a connection using URLConnection class. I found many similiar topics, but here everything is mixed with html code
and I'm not sure how to tell java to "send" certain password and login to this website.

And I'm asking about patience ;)

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar thing to do few days ago.

But first, i have to tell you THAT IT IS NOT SAFE to save your login/password localy. 
You should enter it (at least password) each time. It's up to you ;)

---

First, you should install [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/).
It's an headless browser, so basically you will be able to "simulate" exactly what you usually do to connect to your website.

Then, for scrapping (get the informations you need), you SHOULD use [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org/).
It's gonna help you a lot ! The doc is well done and it's really simple !
For example you can [fill forms](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#fill), clic on links etc .... Nearly everything !

I let you try to write some code, do not hesitate to make an other post if you encounter some problems :)

Good luck !

Comment: This solution is not written in java but i'm pretty sure it's the easiest way to do it. You could parse data you want into JSON and read it in java or anything super easily !